# How to drop a Pandas row if a value is in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, rows

I have a Pandas dataframe with one column, `director_name`, containing directors of movies and another column, `death_year`, containing either `NaN` or a float which describes the year they passed away (example: 1996.00). How do I drop all the rows which possess directors that have died as expressed by a float being in the `death_year` column?

```py
     nconst     director_name       birth_year       death_year 
0   nm0061671   Mary Ellen Bauder    1967.00            NaN     
1   nm0061865   Joseph Bauer          NaN             1996.00   
2   nm0062070   Bruce Baum           1981.00            NaN     
3   nm0062195   Axel Baumann          NaN             2015.00
4   nm0062798   Pete Baxter          1954.00            NaN
```

So in the data frame above, rows 1 and 3 would be dropped because Joseph Bauer died in 1996 and Axel Baumann died in 2015. The result being a dataframe of only living directors:

```py
     nconst     director_name       birth_year       death_year 
0   nm0061671   Mary Ellen Bauder    1967.00            NaN     
1   nm0062070   Bruce Baum           1981.00            NaN     
2   nm0062798   Pete Baxter          1954.00            NaN
```

The DataFrame is huge, it contains too many rows to physically go through and make sure someone didn't enter the death year incorrectly such as 0000.000 by mistake.

Comment: Not exactly the same @Chris. What if someone entered the information wrong and put 0000.00 for the year someone died? So the questions differ. Please remove your negative vote. Thanks

Comment: any input on the 0000.00 part of my above comment @Chris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` and `.notna()`:

```
df.loc[df['birth_year'].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you want to drop rows by death_year use `.isna()`:

```
df.loc[df['death_year'].isna()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       nconst       director_name    birth_year   death_year 
0   nm0061671   Mary Ellen Bauder       1967.00          NaN     
1   nm0062070          Bruce Baum       1981.00          NaN     
2   nm0062798         Pete Baxter       1954.00          NaN
```

In both cases we have the same output for the sample you pasted. You can choose what is better to use for the whole dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when 'death_year' is not NaN, birth_year is.

```
df.dropna(subset=['birth_year'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Accurate observation @chatax. That was just a coincidence. But I learned something from your answer, so thanks